# Docker-compose.yml file format problem

Tags: bash, shell-script, docker, yaml

I'm just testing the construction of a Moodle/Mariadb installation using docker-compose, a lot of information around is conflicting and the differences between versions doesn't help, but I've managed to overcome many errors that appeared - but one I just can't solve.

ERROR: Service "mariadb" uses and undefined network "moodle-net"

moodle-net appears numerous times in the script, so I don't understand why it doesn't find it. This script is from https://git-academy.com/run-moodle-with-docker/ but in it's default format, it threw a lot of errors. Any help would be appreciated.

```
version: '2'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: "bitnami/mariadb:10.1"
    networks:
      - moodle-net
    environment:
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_moodle
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_moodle
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
      - "/home/maria_data:/bitnami"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306" 
  moodle:
    image: "webdevops/php-apache:7.3"
    networks:
      - moodle-net
    environment:
      - MOODLE_DBHOST=mariadb
      - MOODLE_DBPORT=3306
      - MOODLE_DBUSER=bn_moodle
      - MOODLE_DBPASS=''
      - MOODLE_DBNAME=bitnami_moodle
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "/home/moodle_data:/moodledata/moodledata"
      - "/home/gita-moodle:/app"
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    networks:
      - moodle-net
    volumes:
      - "/mariadb_data: 
         driver: local,
         /moodle_data: 
         driver: local"
```

Comment: I have successfully managed to reformat the docker-compose.yml file which now runs successfully. The problem remaining is that the moodle install screen doesn't show in the browser, only the blank apache screen.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the format of the yml file, with a lot of trial and error. Now it creates working Moodle and Mariadb docker containers with no user input.